# OpsCenter 6.1.16 Datastax Agent Creating stomp connection to ERROR [async-dispatch-2] Error connecting via stomp

Tags: https, cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I am facing challenges making an HTTP connection to opscenter through the datastax-agent using SSL:

Datastax Version 5.1.7
Opscenter version 6.1.16

```
  INFO [async-dispatch-2] 2018-05-23 20:58:24,549 Creating stomp connection to <opscenter_host_ip>:61620  ERROR [async-dispatch-2] 2018-05-23 20:58:24,549 Error connecting via stomp.  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/dse/opscenter.jks (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.java.io$fn__9520.invokeStatic(io.clj:229)
        at clojure.java.io$fn__9520.invoke(io.clj:229)
        at clojure.java.io$fn__9433$G__9426__9440.invoke(io.clj:69)
        at clojure.java.io$fn__9532.invokeStatic(io.clj:258)
        at clojure.java.io$fn__9532.invoke(io.clj:254)
        at clojure.java.io$fn__9433$G__9426__9440.invoke(io.clj:69)
        at clojure.java.io$input_stream.invokeStatic(io.clj:136)
        at clojure.java.io$input_stream.doInvoke(io.clj:121)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
        at opsagent.messaging$build_ssl_options.invokeStatic(messaging.clj:25)
        at opsagent.messaging$build_ssl_options.invoke(messaging.clj:23)
        at opsagent.messaging$setup_ssl.invokeStatic(messaging.clj:134)
        at opsagent.messaging$setup_ssl.invoke(messaging.clj:131)
        at opsagent.messaging$setup_conn.invokeStatic(messaging.clj:162)
        at opsagent.messaging$setup_conn.invoke(messaging.clj:157)
        at opsagent.messaging.StompComponent.start(messaging.clj:250)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__2595$G__2589__2597.invoke(component.clj:4)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__2595$G__2588__2600.invoke(component.clj:4)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:641)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invokeStatic(component.clj:116)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invoke(component.clj:115)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
        at opsagent.config_service$update_system$fn__20717.invoke(config_service.clj:218)
        at clojure.lang.ArraySeq.reduce(ArraySeq.java:114)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6544)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6527)
        at opsagent.config_service$update_system.invokeStatic(config_service.clj:212)
        at opsagent.config_service$update_system.doInvoke(config_service.clj:208)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at opsagent.config_service$start_system_BANG_.invokeStatic(config_service.clj:238)
        at opsagent.config_service$start_system_BANG_.invoke(config_service.clj:231)
        at opsagent.config_service$fn__20808$fn__20809$state_machine__4880__auto____20810$fn__20812.invoke(config_service.clj:261)
        at opsagent.config_service$fn__20808$fn__20809$state_machine__4880__auto____20810.invoke(config_service.clj:261)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:1012)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:1011)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:1016)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:1014)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$take_BANG_$fn__4896.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:1025)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__698$fn__699.invoke(channels.clj:95)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My opscenter key store is tried in different locations and gets different errors.

Datastax-agent's address.yaml contents for opscenter running at the stomp interface ip:

```
opscenter_ssl_keystore: /etc/dse/opscenter.jks
opscenter_ssl_keystore_password: <ks pass>
opscenter_ssl_truststore: /etc/dse/truststore.jks
opscenter_ssl_truststore_password: <trst pass>
```

When i placed them in /root/.cassandra/ it throws Permission denied

> ERROR [async-dispatch-8] 2018-05-23 20:37:18,304 Error connecting via
>   stomp.  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/.cassandra/opscenter.jks
>   (Permission denied)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)

When i placed them in /etc/dse/ it throws no such file or directory exists

> INFO [async-dispatch-2] 2018-05-23 21:03:41,423 Creating stomp
>   connection to :61620  ERROR [async-dispatch-2]
>   2018-05-23 21:03:41,423 Error connecting via stomp. 
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/dse/opscenter.jks (No such file or
>   directory)

**both has same permissions.**

**Note:** I have service account cassandra instead of opscenter for my opscenter installation.

```
[root@opscntrmon /]# ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x. 108 root root 12288 May 17 17:40 /etc
[root@opscntrmon /]# ls -ld /etc/dse
drwxr-xr-x 9 cassandra cassandra 4096 May 23 20:56 /etc/dse

[root@opscntrmon /]# ls -ld /root
dr-xr-x---. 11 root root 4096 May 23 16:11 /root
[root@opscntrmon /]# ls -ld /root/.cassandra
drwxrwxrwx 2 cassandra cassandra 4096 May 23 13:22 /root/.cassandra

[root@opscntrmon /]#
```

Any help please?

Comment: What is the permission of the files themself? please post result of `ls -ls /etc/dse/`

Comment: its too 777. 

-rwxrwxrwx 1 cassandra cassandra 1726 May 23 20:09 /etc/dse/truststore.jks 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 cassandra cassandra 2259 May 23 20:09 /etc/dse/opscenter.jks

Comment: Hmm, can you change permissions for these files to 0600 instead?

Comment: yes. I tried that too. Its the same issue. Wondering if there is any parameter that i am missing in either agent config file or the cluster_name.conf file on opscenter. I checked through the entire documentation. Didnt find any clue.

Comment: I suggest to join DataStax Academy Slack, there is an #opscenter channel there.